# How do I change characters at a specific index within a string in rust?

Tags: string, rust, char

I am trying to change a single character at a specific index in a string, but I do not know how to in rust. For example, how would I change the 4th character in "hello world" to 'x', so that it would be "helxo world"?

Comment: Does [replace_range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.replace_range) do what you're looking for?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [`replace_range()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.replace_range) method like this:

```rust
let mut hello = String::from("hello world");
hello.replace_range(3..4,"x");
println!("hello: {}", hello);
```

Output: `hello: helxo world` ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=17c2465b623f28b3b3b7d494ccb5ffc7))

Please note that this will panic if the range to be replaced does not start and end on UTF-8 codepoint boundaries. E.g. this will panic:

```rust
let mut hello2 = String::from("hell world");
hello2.replace_range(4..5,"x"); // panics because  needs more than one byte in UTF-8
```

If you want to replace the nth UTF-8 code point, you have to do something like this:

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let mut hello = String::from("hell world");
    hello.replace_range(
        hello
            .char_indices()
            .nth(4)
            .map(|(pos, ch)| (pos..pos + ch.len_utf8()))
            .unwrap(),
        "x",
    );
    println!("hello: {}", hello);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a0b7e33caf90f88f193d92806c7476c4))

Comment: Good answer, only sad that it requires a wall of source code to accomplish something that simple. Especially, if you have a case, where you do not deal with UTF8 but with plain old 1 byte chars. But that is the world we live in now, I guess ;)

Comment: @BitTickler The wall of code is only required if you want to handle >1-byte characters. You can safely use `replace_range` for 1-byte characters, as it only panics if the range doesn't fall on character boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way of representing a string in Rust is as a contiguous range of bytes encoded as a UTF-8 string.  UTF-8 codepoints can be from one to 4 bytes long, so generally you can't simply replace one UTF-8 codepoint with another because the length might change.  You also can't do simple pointer arithmetic to index into a Rust `String` to the nth character, because again codepoint encodings can be from 1 to 4 bytes long.

So one safe but slow way to do it would be like this, iterating through the characters of the source string, replacing the one you want, then creating a new string:

```
fn replace_nth_char(s: &str, idx: usize, newchar: char) -> String {
    s.chars().enumerate().map(|(i,c)| if i == idx { newchar } else { c }).collect()
}
```

But we can do it in O(1) if we manually make sure the old and new character are single-byte ascii.

```
fn replace_nth_char_safe(s: &str, idx: usize, newchar: char) -> String {
    s.chars().enumerate().map(|(i,c)| if i == idx { newchar } else { c }).collect()
}

fn replace_nth_char_ascii(s: &mut str, idx: usize, newchar: char) {
    let s_bytes: &mut [u8] = unsafe { s.as_bytes_mut() };
    assert!(idx < s_bytes.len());
    assert!(s_bytes[idx].is_ascii());
    assert!(newchar.is_ascii());
    // we've made sure this is safe.
    s_bytes[idx] = newchar as u8;
}
fn main() {
    let s = replace_nth_char_safe("Hello, world!", 3, 'x');
    assert_eq!(s, "Helxo, world!");
    
    let mut s = String::from("Hello, world!");
    replace_nth_char_ascii(&mut s, 3, 'x');
    assert_eq!(s, "Helxo, world!");
}
```

Keep in mind that `idx` parameter in `replace_nth_char_ascii` is not a character index, but instead a byte index.  If there are any multibyte characters earlier in the string, then the byte index and the character index will not correspond.

Comment: There is a strong possibility that the OP is fine with byte indexing, in which case `String::replace_range` is the appropriate tool offered by `String` itself.

Comment: @user4815162342 It looks like you're right, that `String::replace_range() `(which delegates to `Vec::splice`) can replace a range in O(1).  The only drawback I can see is that it takes a `&str` parameter as the replacement, which I think requires a constant statically defined replacement or an allocation.

Comment: I haven't studied the source, but I'd expect it to reallocate if needed or change in-place if the passed replacement is the same size as the range.

Comment: I looked at it.  It's safe and efficient library code, it only allocates and shuffles data if it needs to.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: @rust-coder100 "Replace the nth character" is a simple idea, but to do it both safely and efficiently is not simple.

Comment: Maybe the answer should mention `String::replace_range`, preferably at the top. It's simple, safe (in the Rust sense), efficient, and almost certainly the kind of solution the OP was after.